# Is it possible to limit based on navigational property id's?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, lazy-loading

My model looks like:

```
City
 CityBlocks
   Houses
```

So a city can have many city blocks, and each city block can have many houses.

On a particular page, I have a list of house id's that I want to display.

The page expects a City object, and then loops and displays the city blocks and then the houses.

One thing I am afraid of is that because of lazy-loading, even if I load things based on the list of house id's, it will show all city blocks and houses because of lazy-loading.

How can I avoid this situation for this page?  (I can't disable lazy-loading globally as I use it).

**Update**

So this is what I am doing:

```
var repository = new GenericRepository<Home>();
var homes = repository.Get(home => homeIdList.Contains(home.Id), 
                            includeProperties: "CityBlock, CityBlock.City")
                            .ToList();
City city = homes.Select(h => h.CityBlock.City).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
```

BUT, it isn't working.  Now when I loop over the city it loads everything:

```
@foreach(var block in city.CityBlocks)
{
   foreach(var house in block.Houses)
   {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable lazy loading "locally" for the particular context instance that you are using for your query:

```
var context = new MyContext();
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

It will only be disabled for this context. The next context you are instantiating will have lazy loading enabled again.

**Edit**

It should also work for a single query:

```
try
{
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    // run a query and materialize it here (with .ToList(), or .First(), etc.)
}
finally
{
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm using this as a base (repository pattern with unit of work): http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application  How can I do it with this setup?

Comment: @user1361315: Pass a parameter into the context or unit of work constructor or set a property or something like that. I really don't want to read 20 pages to find the best place. If you are familiar with that tutorial you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: question, so the entire request from this point onwards will have lazy-loading turned off then right?  i wish you could do it for a single call somehow.

Comment: @user1361315: It should be possible for a single query as well, see Edit above.